# Google Places API only returning 1 result

Tags: javascript, google-maps

We saw in a similar question that the Places API should return up to 5 results, but right now we are only able to get 1 result. We were following the tutorial to display museums in Sydney. Does anyone know how to display more than one result? The script for the Maps and Places API is below.

```
let map;
let service;
let infowindow;

function initMap() {
  const sydney = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.867, 151.195);
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: sydney,
    zoom: 15
  });
  const request = {
    query: "Museum",
    fields: ["name", "geometry"]
  };
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, (results, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
  });
}

function createMarker(place) {
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, `findPlaceFromQuery` only ever returns a single result - perhaps the tutorial you followed is old ... or wrong!

Comment: Where did you see the number 5? The number to the best of my knowledge (for the methods that return more than one result (nearbySeartch and textSearch) is 20 at a time, with a maximum of 60 (see: [Accessing Additional Results](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#PlaceSearchPaging))

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#find_place_from_query):

> Find Place from Query takes a text input and returns **a** place.

(note the singular "a place")

To get multiple results use `nearbySearch` (or `textSearch`)

```
 const sydney = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.867, 151.195);
 var request = {
    location: sydney ,
    radius: '10000',
    type: ['museum']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/r3sb1Lpj/)

[image: scrrenshot of map with 20 results]

**code snippet:**

```js
"use strict";

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBIwzALxUPNbatRBj3Xi1Uhp0fFzwWNBkE&libraries=places">
let map;
let service;
let infowindow;

function initMap() {
  const sydney = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.867, 151.195);
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: sydney,
    zoom: 15
  });
 var request = {
    location: sydney ,
    radius: '10000',
    type: ['museum']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      console.log("places service returned "+results.length+" results");
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "places service returned "+results.length+" results";
      for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
  });
}

function createMarker(place) {
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 90%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Searches</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

nearbySearch or textSearch returns complete information for up to 20 suitable places (no more). Full - this means the atmosphere, working hours, photos and more. And for all this, Google takes a lot of money. I think that's why in their api there is no way to get a list of the names of organizations in the building, for example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).